# JavaScript percentage calculation functions

Tags: javascript

I am building a calculator and I'm aware of what these functions do.

What I basically want feedback on is: Do I need to comment this or is there sufficient information to ascertain its purpose:

```
function percentOfValue(percentage, of) {
    return (percentage / 100) * of;
}

function whatPercentOfValue(small, large) {
    return (small / large) * 100
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code level comments usually lose their context if not properly maintained. Using self descriptive variable names is a good choice. Appreciate your efforts in keeping the code highly readable.

- First method, is trying to get the Percentage value, I would update the method definition to `getPercentOfValue(from, percentage)`.
- Second method, is trying to calculate percent rate, I would update the method definition to `getPercentRate(newValue, originalValue)` to follow the terminology in formula.

Comment: A couple of small changes that give absolute clarity, thank you.

Comment: I'd suggest not to use the prefix `get` as these are not "getters" as customarily used in Java. Instead use, for example, `calc(ulate)`.

Comment: Thankyou @RoToRa that does make sense if it would change the perceived use. Other than that change, I think its fairly self explanitory, to be fair it may never see the light of day after I close up this development session but you never know so i would rather not be beating myself up down the road for not making commenting it or making it readable. I am of the principle that a comment should only be used when there is no way to make it obvious. I hope ive managed that here.